# SQL optimization: Finding first unwatched video using no subselect

Tags: mysql, sql

My question. I think I have a performance killing subquery but can't prove it. My first tries using JOIN failed. *Can somebody provide a more high performing solution or confirm that this is indeed acceptable as it is?*

I have two tables, one that contains a todo-list (joblist) and one that tracks every user's progress (userprogress). A job **can** but must not be to watch a video. (It's a site for e-learning.)

When videos have been watched they are automatically set to 'finished' on an enum field. Users may also skip videos manually (status = 'skipped').

Table structures are provided below.

To get the first video that a user have not watched at all (no record in userprogress) or has begun to watch (status = 'begun') I am using this query.

I have set indexes on ever field that is being used for selection or ordering. However I am unsure if they are all needed.

The SELECT statement has two parts

1. An inner subselect, where I fetch *all seen or skipped* videos
2. The main statement, where I fetch the *first* video *not* among the ones found by (1)

There is a named parameter for PHP (:email), to avoid SQL-injection.

```
SELECT jl.where_to_do_it FROM joblist AS jl
INNER JOIN userprogress AS up
ON (jl.joblistID = up.joblistID)
WHERE jl.what_to_do = 'video'
     AND jl.joblistID NOT IN
      (
        SELECT injl.joblistID
        FROM joblist AS injl
        INNER JOIN userprogress AS inup
        ON (injl.joblistID = inup.joblistID)
        WHERE
             (inup.status = 'finished' OR inup.status = 'skipped')
          AND
             inup.email = :email
          AND
             injl.what_to_do = 'video'
      )
ORDER BY jl.joborder ASC
LIMIT 0,1
```

This is the output from EXPLAIN, which *I need some help understanding*.

```
id select_type  table     type  possible_keys                 key         key_len  ref          rows   Extra
1  PRIMARY      jl        ref   PRIMARY,what_to_do            what_to_do  602      const        9      Using where; Using filesort
1  PRIMARY      up        ref   joblistID                     joblistID   3        jl.joblistID 1      Using index
2  DEP-SUB      injl  eq_ref    PRIMARY,what_to_do            PRIMARY     3        func         1      Using where
2  DEP-SUB      inup  eq_ref    nodup,email,joblistID,status  nodup       455      const,func   1      Using where
```

The create table commands:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `joblist` (
  `joblistID` mediumint(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `what_to_do` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci NOT NULL,
  `where_to_do_it` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci NOT NULL,
  `joborder` mediumint(6) NOT NULL,
  `track` enum('fast','slow','bonus') COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'slow',
  `chapter` tinyint(11) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'What book chapter it relates to',
  PRIMARY KEY (`joblistID`),
  KEY `nodupjobs` (`joborder`,`chapter`),
  KEY `what_to_do` (`what_to_do`),
  KEY `where_to_do_it` (`where_to_do_it`),
  KEY `joborder` (`joborder`),
  KEY `track` (`track`),
  KEY `chapter` (`chapter`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_swedish_ci COMMENT='Suggested working order';


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `userprogress` (
  `upID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'user id',
  `joblistID` mediumint(9) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'foreign key',
  `progressdata` varchar(300) COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'JSON object describing progress',
  `percentage_complete` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` enum('begun','skipped','finished') COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci DEFAULT 'begun',
  `lastupdate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `approved` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`upID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `nodup` (`email`,`joblistID`),
  KEY `email` (`email`),
  KEY `joblistID` (`joblistID`),
  KEY `status` (`status`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_swedish_ci COMMENT='Keep track of what the user has done';
```

Comment: I've got two working (and one not working) answers. I've so far only upvoted both. If there is a discernible advantage to one over the other, I need help in deciding which one to accept as the accepted answer. (Or perhaps someone will come along with an even better solution.) I'll wait a day or two before I set an answer as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are correct.  IN and NOT IN are particularly bad performers in mysql.  Here is a revised version:

```
SELECT jl.where_to_do_it
FROM joblist jl INNER JOIN
     userprogress up
     ON (jl.joblistID = up.joblistID)
 WHERE jl.what_to_do = 'video' and
       not exists (
           (SELECT 1
            FROM joblist injl INNER JOIN
                 userprogress inup
                 ON (injl.joblistID = inup.joblistID)
            WHERE (inup.status = 'finished' OR inup.status = 'skipped') and
                  inup.email = :email and
                  injl.what_to_do = 'video' and
                  ini1.joblistid = j1.joblistid
          )
ORDER BY jl.joborder ASC
LIMIT 0,1
```

Comment: I'll give this a try tomorrow (time to sleep). Thanks for the answer. I'll reward you if it works. (I think it will!)

Comment: Quick question before I turn the computer off. Do I need both the ON statement and the last equals comparison in the subselect? They seem to my untrained eye to do the same thing.

Comment: Yes.  The last equal is replacing the "not in" condition.  The rest is your original query.

Comment: Yes, I see now. (It was 3 am when I wrote that last comment.) My initial tests confirm that your query works, but it lacks one parenthesis, to close the not exists clause, and it spells "injl" as "ini1" in the lat equals clause. My abbreviations were: j-l = job list, i-n-j-l = inner job list, u-p, user progress, inup = inner user progress.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're running in circles... Your subquery is looking for Videos with status finished or skipped and then in the outter query lookin for the ones that don't have that status, I would change that for a condition like this

```
SELECT jl.where_to_do_it FROM joblist AS jl
INNER JOIN userprogress AS up
ON (jl.joblistID = up.joblistID)
WHERE jl.what_to_do = 'video'
 AND up.status <> 'finished' AND inup.status <> 'skipped'
 AND up.email = :email
 AND jl.what_to_do = 'video'
```

Or maybe I understand wrong, anyway the problem seems to be the NOT IN (i will not suggest to use this ever) instead try changing the subquery in the condition and do a Left join with it and add a condition `And SQ.joblistID IS NULL`, something like this

```
 SELECT jl.where_to_do_it FROM joblist AS jl
 INNER JOIN userprogress AS up
 ON (jl.joblistID = up.joblistID)
 LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT injl.joblistID
    FROM joblist AS injl
    INNER JOIN userprogress AS inup
    ON (injl.joblistID = inup.joblistID)
    WHERE
         (inup.status = 'finished' OR inup.status = 'skipped')
      AND
         inup.email = :email
      AND
         injl.what_to_do = 'video'
  ) SQ ON jl.joblistID = SQ.joblistID
 WHERE jl.what_to_do = 'video'
 AND SQ.joblistID IS NULL      
 ORDER BY jl.joborder ASC
```

But i think the first option will work...

Hope it helps

Comment: The first suggestion fails, because userprogress may not have a matching record at all. It should work both when there is a status = 'begun' and when there is no record at all _for that user_. Looking at 2nd suggestion....

Comment: The second suggestion seem to work, judged by my initial tests. For that, I'll give you an upvote.

Comment: thanks for the upvote. I think the first solution might work if you change the `INNER JOIN` for a `LEFT JOIN` and change the conditions (that involve the userprogress table) in the `WHERE` part to the `ON`conditions in the join. If not, well second solution will work faster than the `NOT IN` or the `NOT EXISTS`, i use this method all the time.